# Can build solution in VS2010 but not in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, migration

I have a solution with four projects in it which was initially created in VS2010.

I have now opened the project in VS2012 and everythings works fine, except when I am publishing the project (Web application) (building and testing works fine!).

When publishing I get the error "Could not get dependencies for project reference 'ProjectName.Model'".

If I then open the project (same folder!) back in VS2010 I can build it from there without problems.

Of course I can use VS2012 for all development and go back to VS2010 everytime I need to publish, but I would rather find a permanent solution to how to solve this!

I have tried removing my ProjectName.Model from the project and re-inserting it in VS2012, but it still did not solve the problem.

EDIT: 2013-08-06 13:37: Have found the following error msg: Could not get dependencies for project reference 'ProjectName.Model'Warning: Unable to update auto-refresh reference 'ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll'. Cannot find assembly 'G:\Dev\2012\JournalBase\WebSite\Bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll'.

Have taken over the project from a colleague, and I can see that I do not have the folder G:\Dev\2012.... So I searched for the term "AjaxControlToolkit", but couldn't find it anywhere as text in the solution! Anyone knows where I should be able to find the reference? Apparently not in the .sln file or the .csproj file for project ProjectName.Model.

Comment: Just a query since you have .model extension, are you using entity framework?

Comment: Check your target framework. It could be you are referencing .NET 4.5 but the project could have been referenced with .NET 4.0.

Comment: Bravo11: Am using ActiveRecord. So not using MS's version.

Comment: luke2012: Have just checked, and that was not the problem.